# Error while running epub file in android

Tags: android, epub3

I want to build and run a epub content in android and refered http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android and trying to implement the same but i am getting error like

```
02-01 10:08:15.726: D/dalvikvm(27839): Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-01 10:08:15.926: I/dalvikvm(27839): Could not find method org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger, referenced from method nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.<clinit>
02-01 10:08:15.926: W/dalvikvm(27839): VFY: unable to resolve static method 4251: Lorg/slf4j/LoggerFactory;.getLogger (Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
02-01 10:08:15.926: D/dalvikvm(27839): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0002
02-01 10:08:16.066: I/dalvikvm(27839): Could not find method org.slf4j.Logger.error, referenced from method nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.getPackageResourceHref
02-01 10:08:16.066: W/dalvikvm(27839): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 4249: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;.error (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
02-01 10:08:16.066: D/dalvikvm(27839): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0045
02-01 10:08:16.066: I/dalvikvm(27839): Could not find method org.slf4j.Logger.error, referenced from method nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.processPackageResource
02-01 10:08:16.066: W/dalvikvm(27839): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 4249: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;.error (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
02-01 10:08:16.066: D/dalvikvm(27839): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x000f
02-01 10:08:16.066: W/dalvikvm(27839): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lnl/siegmann/epublib/epub/EpubReader;
02-01 10:08:16.066: D/AndroidRuntime(27839): Shutting down VM
02-01 10:08:16.066: W/dalvikvm(27839): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e99930)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at com.example.epub2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
02-01 10:08:16.066: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.<clinit>(EpubReader.java:33)
```

My code is::

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try { 
      // find InputStream for book
      InputStream is = getAssets().open("ww.epub");
      Book book = new EpubReader().readEpub(is);
      // Load Book from inputStream


      // Log the book's authors
      Log.i("epublib", "author(s): " + book.getMetadata().getAuthors());

      // Log the book's title
      Log.i("epublib", "title: " + book.getTitle());

      // Log the book's coverimage property
      Bitmap coverImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage()
          .getInputStream());
      Log.i("epublib", "Coverimage is " + coverImage.getWidth() + " by "
          + coverImage.getHeight() + " pixels");

      // Log the tale of contents
      logTableOfContents(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {
      return;
    }
    for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
      StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        tocString.append("\t");
      }
      tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
      Log.i("epublib", tocString.toString());

      logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

and yes i imported two jar libraries as they mentioned!! I am not finding the solution could anyone help me out?

Comment: which two jar file you are using?

Comment: @Pankaj Getting started

    Download epublib-core-latest.jar from https://github.com/downloads/psiegman/epublib/epublib-core-latest.jar
    Download slf4j-android

Comment: sorry i mean which two jar file you are using i don't required but i am asinkg you so

Comment: [epublib](https://github.com/downloads/psiegman/epublib/epublib-core-latest.jar) and [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/android/)  @Pankaj

Comment: i had use same code and jar file for  me it's working but in some big epub file it outor memmory so i am finding something related it.

Answer (score 3):

```
02-01 10:08:15.926: I/dalvikvm(27839): Could not find method org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger, referenced from method nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.<clinit>
```

this error shows that your package didnot loaded jar files . You have to add the two jar files in libs folder and append them to the build path